# How to Copy Large Directory to External Hard Drive Linux

Tags: linux, tar, cp, ubuntu-server

I've formatted a 3TB external hard drive as ext4 using fdisk (actually gnu fdisk), mounted it at /media/external and am trying to copy my entire home directory to it.

My first attempt I thought was successful, but after a while when the process stopped, I couldn't cd into the copied home directory.  cd seemed to fail:

```
sudo: cd: command not found
```

I then thought there might be some limit to cp and then tried again using tar.

```
cd /from-stuff/
tar cf – . | (cd /to-stuff; tar xvf -)
```

I measured my home directory size to be ~100G.  When in my home directory, I ran:

```
du -ch | grep total
```

I've mounted it as:

```
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sdd1 /media/external
```

Note that I could not mount `/dev/sdd` which shows up on `sudo fdisk -l` while /dev/sdd1 does not.

When formatting I did the most default setup, 1 partition, default everything else.  I confirmed that formatting correctly by not having any 'invalid partition table errors.'  I'm new to this so please bear with.  I may have accidentally chosen GUID? but do not know how to check that or re-format away from that to whatever it may need to be.

Is there anything glaring that I did incorrectly?  Can someone maybe offer an fdisk sequence to really make sure everything is 1 basic partition formatted as ext4?

Here's my documentation on what I did to format.  Please clarify/augment if you can.  There may have been a failed gparted attempt before this:

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sdb # this will pull up an interactive menu
n       # create a new partition
p       # create a primary partition
[enter] # use default value of 1 for the partition number
[enter] # use default value of 256 for first sector
[enter] # use default value for last sector
w       # write these settings and leave the interactive menu

# make the file system
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1
```

Comment: `sudo cd` doesn't make any sense. What would be the point of a process that changed its own current working directory and then terminated?

Answer (score 1):

- about the `sudo: cd: command not found`

  That one is normal. cd is a shell builtin. This doesn't mean the destination directory doesn't exist. Try "su - root" if you need to be root to go to that dir, and then cd to the destination.
- about the fact /dev/sdd can't be mounted

  /dev/sdd is an entire sd disk (including its master partitino table, everything, even the unpartitionned space). It is not a partition. /dev/sdd1 is its first partition. And beware: you show you want to mount /dev/sdd1 , but you show a fdisk on /dev/sdb1 (another disk! /dev/sdb is different from /dev/sdd)
- if that new drive is to make backups : you should, instead of using tar | ( cd dest ; tar), which copies everything each time (and won't delete destination files/dirs if they get deleted on the source), you shuold look into the command `rsync`. Especially locally (but also when copying to a remote location, as rsync will only copy the changed parts of each changed files, not the entirety of the file). But **beware** its usage: rsync can be tricky at first. Don't use the "--delete" option before reading a lot about it, it could wipe out the source or destination files if they have no match on the other side... see the different ways to specify source/destinatino directories, sometimes you'll add the trailing "/", sometimes not, depending on how you want rsync to act.

Comment: thank you all for the replies.  i can't vote up any of them because i have no reputation yet

Comment: thank you for the warnings.  to clarify the original post, they were on different computers.  i formatted on a netbook and mounted on another tower so /dev/sdd vs. /dev/sdb was safe

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your problem is that fdisk doesn't do large disks. It has been superseded by `parted`.

It's similar to fdisk, just updated for newer technology. Assuming the disk is /dev/sdb (check with `sudo parted -l`):

1. `sudo parted /dev/sdb`
2. mklabel (type gpt)
3. mkpart (default anwswers make one max size partition)
4. q to exit parted
5. `sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1` to make the filesystem.

After that it should just be a matter of `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/external`. It would be a good idea to make sure you own the directory first with `sudo chown tarabyte.tarabyte /media/external`

I usually use `rsync` for large copies, even local. It has better output and resumes easily if there are interruptions.

`rsync -avh --progress /from-stuff /to-stuff`

See `man rsync` for more info.

Comment: i upgraded to gnu-fdisk to handle the 2TB limit i guess fdisk had.  i will try parted though, thank you

Comment: hitting enter when prompted for the default start does not work.  how am i supposed to know what number i should place here?

Comment: Oh yeah. I usually use 1, for 1 megabyte. Aligns it correctly. Sorry about that.